# Two-word surname abbreviation with alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I am using biblatex for my bibliography, and the style is alphabetic. More precisely, in the preamble I have

```
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxnames=99,style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

In the bibliography I need to include a two word surname. This is what I have in the .bib file

```
@article{dJ97,
author = {de Jong, A. J.},
title = {Families of curves and alterations},
journaltitle = {Annales de l'institut Fourier},
year = {1997},
volume = {47},
number = {2},
pages = {599-621},
}
```

In this way, the abbreviation produced is [Jon97], and is alphabetized as a surname starting with J. On the other hand, I have always seen this author alphabetized under d (which I guess should be the correct outcome), and the abbreviation including the "d" of "de". After a quick look online, I just found co-authored works of the author cited in a bibliography style as I have, and the abbreviation is "dJ" followed by other capital letters for the other authors. So, in my case, I guess that the right outcome should be something like [dJo97], or [dJon97].

Which one should the right outcome in my case? How do I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `shorthand`, as suggested by [Myles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427515/105447), is indeed a good alternative for individual cases. But, if something more automatic is needed, `biblatex` has an option `useprefix` controlling the use of name prefixes, and which is, by default, set to `false`. You can use `useprefix=true` as a package option to `biblatex` and prefixes will be used throughout the document. In your case, it will be considered in the construction of `labelalpha`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxnames=99,style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{dJ97,
author = {de Jong, A. J.},
title = {Families of curves and alterations},
journaltitle = {Annales de l'institut Fourier},
year = {1997},
volume = {47},
number = {2},
pages = {599-621},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \cite{dJ97}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is the `biblatex`y way of doing this. Unfortunately, I can't upvote this answer twice so it comes out above the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a field you can add to your `.bib` entry  called `shorthand` which allows you to enter a specific citation abbreviation. I can't advise which style, [dJo97] vs [dJon97], is the 'correct' one. This depends on what the citation style guide you are following recommends. But say you wanted to use [dJon97], you would add the following to your `.bib` entry:

```
shorthand = {dJon97},
```

Here is a minimal working example based on what you provided:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxnames=99,style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{dJ97,
author = {de Jong, A. J.},
shorthand = {dJon97},
title = {Families of curves and alterations},
journaltitle = {Annales de l'institut Fourier},
year = {1997},
volume = {47},
number = {2},
pages = {599-621},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text\cite{dJ97}

\end{document}
```

[image]